# Meromorphic functions with only one pole on a compact Riemann surface separate points

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, meromorphic-functions

I‘m currently working on understanding compact Riemann surfaces.

I‘ve already got that we have non-zero meromorphic functions on a compact Riemann surface which only have one pole. In the literature I found, it‘s stated that from that point on, it is trivial to see that these meromorphic functions actually separate points, moreover that we have for two points finitely many such meromorphic functions.

I suppose that the finiteness follows from the fact that the Riemann surface is compact but I’m not sure how.

When researching, I found that Riemann's existence theorem actually states that the meromorphic functions on a compact Riemann surface separate points, but I don‘t think that I want or need to use this to get the desired result in my situation (mostly because it‘s stated as trivial)

I would much appreciate for example literature that explains those points in depth and ideas on how to see this.

Comment: Dear eliStraw, did you delete your previous question ? I would appreciate that you put it back : it took me few minutes to type the answer and it might be useful to other readers. Thank you !

Comment: Oh i‘m really sorr! I didn‘t notice that i deleted it when trying to edit it. I‘ll put it back once i figure out how!

Comment: No problems :) Hope it helped !